# a belongs to J(R) if and only if Ra is left quasi regular left ideal of R

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

$ a\,\in\,J(R)\, \, if\, \,and\, \,only\, \,if\, \,Ra\, \,is\, \,a\, \,left\, \, quasi\, \,regular\, \,left \, \,ideal\, \,of \, \,R $

Here $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$ where $R$ is a non commutative ring without an identity. 
I need help with both the necessary and sufficient part.
I am unable to show that $ra$ for all $ r\in R$ will be left quasi regular whenever $a$ is and that quasi regularity of $a$ makes $Ra$ left quasi regular

Edit :-

My attempt :-

If $Ra$ is a left quasiregular left ideal of $R$ then $Ra\subseteq J(R)$ $\implies$ $Ra\subseteq I$ for all maximal regular right ideals I of R. 
Now for all such I there some $e\in R$ specific to that I such that $ (a - ea)\in I$. 
$Ra\subseteq I$ for all such$ I\implies ea\in  I\implies (a - ea + ea) = a\in I\implies a\in J(R) $

Conversely, let $a\in J(R)\implies Ra\subseteq J(R)\,\implies Ra $ is left quasiregular.

Thanks to the comments.

Comment: Hi: this question will be perceived as a question dump since you haven't contributed any context.  You should probably rectify that as soon as possible if you want to attract help.  [This is how you can add context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335). Use the edit button.

Comment: You should also never, never split the question up between the title and body.  It has to be in the body, and can be echoed in the title.

Comment: The hard direction is [already answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025494/29335)

Comment: @rschwieb Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question a little bit.

Comment: Well... your biggest problem is your approach assumes a lot more than the question asks you to prove, and won't work.  In fact, left quasiregularity of $a$ does *not* imply $ra$ is left quasiregular. So... you'll have to rethink your approach.

Comment: @rschwieb Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: You need to use the fact that $a$ is in $J(R)$, not just that it's quasiregular...

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks. I have added my attempt. Is it alright?

Comment: No, you are begging the question when you say "If $Ra$ is a left quasiregular left ideal of $R$ then $Ra\subseteq J(R)$". You have no idea if $Ra\subseteq J(R)$. You don't even know $a\in J(R)$. That is precisely what you are trying to show...

Comment: @rschwieb Isn't every left quasiregular left ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of the ring?

Comment: I am assuming one to show the other.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain now what exactly you are assuming, without any other reasoning clouding the issue.  What I see look like you are assuming the right hand side and a stronger version of the left hand side to prove the left hand side.

Comment: If you already proved elsewhere that $J(R)$ is the largest left quasiregular ideal of $R$ and contains all other left quasiregular ideals, then this problem is trivial.  I was inclined to believe you did not have that result yet.

Comment: @rschwieb Okay. I understand what you are saying.